# SQL Query with Inner Joins

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this Query in SQL:

```
SELECT c.company, sum(i.grand_total) FROM billing_invoices i 
INNER JOIN billing_salesman_commission b ON i.invoice_number = b.invoice
INNER JOIN customer c ON i.customer_sequence = c.sequence 
WHERE 
i.status = 'Unpaid' and DATE(i.datetime) >= '2015-10-01' 
GROUP BY c.sequence
```

Which returns the correct data, however its moving the decimal point for the `grand_total` column that its summing up

As an example, when i run `SELECT sum(grand_total) from billing_invoices WHERE customer_sequence = '270'`, it is returning `35.29` however when i run my first query, its returning `352.90000915527344`

Comment: what about other conditions / joins you had? the correct way to see if the sum is really correct is to remove your sum and group by, get all rows to excel, add them together

Comment: You have tagged both MySQL as well as SQL Server. Which one are you using?

Comment: MySQL, i will remove the other. was an accident

Comment: You have `c.company` in your output, but you are not grouping by it. This could cause all sorts of funky results, not just limited to your sum() issue. If your sequence is unique for each customer, then you will be fine, but why not `GROUP BY customer` then. Also do you have multiple `billing_salesman_commission` records for each invoice or multiple `customer.sequence` results for each `i.customer_sequence` Somewhere, your joins are doing a one:many and causing your sum aggregate to blow up. Try running the query without the `sum` and `group by` and see where the duplicates are coming in from.

Comment: there are multiple rows in `billing_salesman_commission` for each row in `billing_invoices`. there are no duplicates - its just putting decimal point in the wrong place

Comment: It's not putting the decimal point in the wrong place. It's multiplying your results by 10. Suggesting that you are getting 10 results for each `billing_invoice` record.

Comment: There ARE duplicate billing_invoice records in your result set of this query if your have a 1:many relationship between billing_invoice and billing_salesman_commisions tables. Run the query without the aggregation and using a `SELECT *` you will immediately see the problem.

Comment: okay, sorry i misunderstood. i removed the sum and group by and tried both of these queries: `SELECT * FROM billing_invoices i, billing_salesman_commission b WHERE i.invoice_number = b.invoice AND DATE(i.datetime) >= '2015-10-01' AND i.status = 'Unpaid' and b.salesmanid = '5948'` and `SELECT * FROM billing_invoices i INNER JOIN billing_salesman_commission b ON i.invoice_number = b.invoice WHERE DATE(i.datetime) >= '2015-10-01' AND i.status = 'Unpaid' and b.salesmanid = '5948'` and they both return multiple rows (duplicates)

Comment: please update your question. the formatting in comments is awful

Comment: your assumptions about the effects of joins are probably flawed. If the joined table has 10 rows matching the join condition the result will have 10 times the result of your join-less query.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different where clauses. Are you sure that customer_sequence = 270 returns the exact same results as status = "unpaid" and datetime >= 2015-10-01? I bet it's not.

You could also be getting different results because you are running a sum() in a group by in one query, and then a sum() without a group by in the second. It's hard to say without knowing the underlying data. There are other factors with the relationship to the join tables and the data integrity on "sequence."

Work through the joins one at a time and verify you are getting the data you expect. Start by removing the "group by" clause and see